# Scala - meaning of "companion contains its own main method, which means no static forwarder can be generated"

Tags: scala, jar, jvm, sbt

Given the following class and its companion object:

```scala
class B extends A

object B extends B
```

Where A is an abstract class in another file:

```scala
abstract class A { 
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("hey")
}
```

The above code is packaged into an uber-jar using the sbt assembly plugin, where the entry point is `object B` main method inherited from `class B`.

The above works fine. It runs. No problem at all.

Hoewver, sbt keeps warning:

```plaintext
[warn] B has the main method with parameter type Array[String], but B will not be a runnable program.
[warn]   Reason: companion contains its own main method, which means no static forwarder can be generated.
[warn] object B extends B
```

1. Do you know the meaning of this warning?
2. And why sbt assurance that `object B` won't run, doesn't happen?

Thank you.

Comment: While I agree the error is weird, what is the point of `class B`?

Comment: We need class B as a class, not an object, in order to create it and override fields in tests and also in runtime code. I agree that using B just as an object would be simpler, but it would not permit modular testing (overwriting fields) and not permit creating the class for other use cases.

Comment: Your entry point should only be an entry point and should not need to be overridden on testing; mainly because it shouldn't need unit tests.

Comment: What need to be overwritten are other fields I didn't add in the question. And, the main method must be inherited, because we needed a common implementation for all child classes

Comment: Sure you can overwrite those in the object itself, again I agree the error is weird but I don't see a point in `class B` to exist.

Answer (score 1):

For a class to be runnable in java, `main` needs to be static. Yours isn't, so, the object isn't runnable. That's what compiler is telling you.

Just rename `main` in `A` to something else, and then add a `main` in the object, that calls it.

Comment: Thanks, Dima. That is exactly what I was looking to avoid. :)

Comment: @YFI I know .. people often look to avoid the weirdest things

Answer (score 1):

It does not run for me.

I have this file `B.scala`.

```scala
package foo.bar

abstract class A {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("hey")
}

class B extends A

object B extends B
```

When I try to run `foo.bar.B` I get an error:

```
sbt> runMain foo.bar.B
[info] running foo.bar.B
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: foo.bar.B.main is not static
```

And the reason is exactly as the warning says. **Class** `B` contains a non-static main method which it inherited from class `A`. You can't have 2 methods with exactly the same name and type signature in one class, even if one is static and another in non-static. This means that the compiler cannot generate a static main method in **class** `B` that forwards to the non-static main method in **object** `B`.

Why it does run correctly for you I don't know.

It's not so hard to avoid this problem. Just don't use the companion object as an entrypoint. I.e. rename either class `B` or object `B`.

```scala
package foo.bar

abstract class A {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("hey")
}

class BClass extends A

object B extends BClass
```

Comment: Interesting it doesn't run for you. In my case, the abstract class is in another file, but I can't think of any reason why this shoudl matter here.

Comment: Moreover, I didnt try running with sbt this way. I'm using only as a uber jar packaged by the assembly plugin. Again, might be that assembly is slightly different than simple compilation?

Comment: Apart from shading I wouldn't think that the assembly plugin makes changes to the class files themselves. When I run the uber jar with `java -jar` then I get `Error: Main method is not static in class foo.bar.A`. Maybe some JVMs are more lenient and allow invoking non-static main methods? Or maybe due to some extra complexity in your codebase—perhaps in combination with incremental compilation—the static method is generated somehow...

Comment: @YFl You can avoid this issue altogether by renaming either class or object `B`. Then you don't have to rename your `main` method.

Comment: Thanks. Will check this.